# Listing all the numbers within a range where range is specified in two cells - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) sheet with the following data:

```
col1      col2    col3    col4
dvdtable    6      52      57
tvunit      2      30      31
```

I need to copy each row in another sheet, however making 6 copies of the dvdtable row and 2 copies of the tvunit row. (col2 is referring to the quantity). In addition I need to create a new column where for each of the 6 dvdtable rows I include 52,53,54,55,56,57 respectively in the new column.  See the result below:

```
col1      col2    col3 
dvdtable    6      52
dvdtable    6      53
dvdtable    6      54
dvdtable    6      55
dvdtable    6      56
dvdtable    6      57
tvunit      2      30
tvunit      2      31
```

I managed to produce the code that makes multiple copies of rows thanks to another question in your forum, but I am stuck with the last part of the programming, where I need to create the list of numbers within the range given in column 3 and column 4 for each type of furniture.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

You likely have to change the sheetnames.

```
Option Explicit
Sub whyDidIDoThisForYou()

    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim numbRows As Integer
    Dim curWriteRow As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim values() As String

    numbRows = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row - 1 'assumes heading
    curWriteRow = 1
    ReDim values(1 To numbRows, 1 To 4)

    For i = 1 To numbRows

        'read all values in from initial datasheet
        For j = 1 To 4
            values(numbRows, j) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        Next j

        'write to next sheet
        'get number of things to write
        temp = values(numbRows, 4) - values(numbRows, 3)

        'start writing the "output" sheet!
        For j = 0 To temp
               Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(curWriteRow, 1).Value = values(numbRows, 1)
               Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(curWriteRow, 2).Value = values(numbRows, 2)
               Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(curWriteRow, 3).Value = values(numbRows, 3) + j
               curWriteRow = curWriteRow + 1
        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays as below which is much quicker than writing to ranges cell by cell

The code below

- reads the orginal data into a variant array `Y`
- loops through each row of `Y`  (`lngCnt2`)
- runs through that `Y` by the number of times specifiec in colulmB   (`lngCnt3`)
- dumps the new records to a second variant array `X`
- dumps `x` to a range starting in `E1` when finished

[image]

```
Sub SplicenDice()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long
Dim lngCnt3 As Long
Dim lngCnt4 As Long
Dim X
Dim Y
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
Y = rng1.Value2
lngCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B:B"))
ReDim X(1 To lngCnt, 1 To 3)
For lngCnt2 = 1 To UBound(Y, 1)
For lngCnt3 = 1 To Y(lngCnt2, 2)
lngCnt4 = lngCnt4 + 1
X(lngCnt4, 1) = Y(lngCnt2, 1)
X(lngCnt4, 2) = Y(lngCnt2, 2)
X(lngCnt4, 3) = Y(lngCnt2, 3) + lngCnt3 - 1
Next
Next
[e1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
End Sub
```